# How to install catalyst.api?

Tags: python

I have a probabily obvious question. I have not used catalyst.api yet.

I have his code:

```
from catalyst.api import record

from catalyst.utils.run_algo import run_algorithm
```

But, I get this error:

> No module named api.

How can I install catalyst?

I install it using `pip install catalyst`.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: use code blocks

Comment: Are you using the correct project interpreter?

Comment: Did you name your running file `catalyst.py`?

Comment: I am using Spyder. No, I called my file something else.

Comment: Okay, but what is the filename you are running?

Comment: The name of my python code is untitled0.py I put everything in one .py file.

Comment: what is catalyst, can paste the link to the library/docs?

Comment: I want to run this code: https://github.com/enigmampc/catalyst/blob/master/catalyst/examples/portfolio_optimization.py

Comment: I pip installed it... There is indeed no `api` module

Comment: You installed the wrong thing... https://enigmampc.github.io/catalyst/install.html#installing-with-pip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I install catalyst?

It's in [their documentation](https://enigmampc.github.io/catalyst/install.html#installing-with-pip).

```
pip install enigma-catalyst matplotlib
```

And you need matplotlib because it depends on Numpy for linear algebra routines

The easiest way to get Numpy on your machine would probably be using Anaconda, not pure Python, as also mentioned on that page

> The preferred method to install Catalyst is via the `conda` package manager

Answer (score 2):

It seems you installed the wrong `catalyst` package.

When doing `pip install catalyst` and then doing `pip show catalyst` I see:

```
Name: catalyst
Version: 0.1.post1
Summary: A dataflow process network runner
Home-page: https://github.com/quantz-nl/pypeline
Author: Fabian van der Werf
Author-email: fvanderwerf@gmail.com
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requires:
```

This is not the right package.

You can install the right package e.g. via `git clone https://github.com/enigmampc/catalyst.git`.